# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value in some cases with identical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 databases that I'm looking at, when I run this query on both, one returns a value and one throws a conversion error

> code_desc is a varchar column and has some varchars in it

```
SELECT *
FROM t_ccs_admin_code
WHERE code_grp = '50042' AND code_desc = 015105
```

I've ran a comparison on the table `t_ccs_admin_code` and all of the data appears to match across the databases. I know I could fix this, but at this point I'm really just trying to figure out why I would get this in one environment and not the other.

Comment: If `code_desc` is a varchar, why are you comparing the value to an int?

Comment: I understand that there's a better way to do this and I'm resolving the code that is causing the issue. I'm just trying to understand why this would even work in one environment when the data is exactly the same across both.

Comment: @corey: you can try running `SELECT  * FROM t_css_admin_code WHERE code_desc IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(INT, code_desc) IS NULL` on both setups and see if there are unconvertable entries. Also one of your setups may have, say, an index on `code_grp`. If this index is used and, by coincidence, there are no invalid entries just on this group, the query may work on one server and not work on another.

Comment: Hmmm, the indexes are the same. I'm thinking it has to be something at the database level as the schema, data, and SQL version are all the same.

Comment: You need to compare the results of this query on both databases to see where the difference lies:  
SELECT * FROM t_ccs_admin_code WHERE code_grp = '50042'

Answer (score 0):

When you compare a string column to a number, SQL Server -- for better or worse -- attempts to convert the string to a number.  This is the cause of your conversion error if any problem arises.

You should be doing something like:

```
code_desc = '015105'
```

Or perhaps:

```
code_desc like '%015105%'
```

The conversion from string to int works when all characters are digits -- or even if there are spaces at the beginning or end.  However, it easily fails.  So, you'll get conversion errors if any row contains a value like `1.23`, `a`, or `1 1` or a zillion other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this query instead

```
SELECT *
FROM t_ccs_admin_code
WHERE code_grp = '50042' AND cast(code_desc as varchar)='015105'
```

It seems that one DB has the column code_desc as int/numeric/bigint and other has the same column as varchar type.

The above query will run on both